# A tough set theory problem

Tags: combinatorics

$A_1,A_2, A_3,\ldots, A_n$ are subsets of a set $S$ with $|S|=2019$ such that the union of any three of the $A_k$s gives $S$ whereas the union of any two isn't equal to $S$. Find the maximum value of $n$.

I am finding this problem very hard to do. I guess it involves the knowledge of very advanced set theory which probably I don't know.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a competitive maths problem.

Comment: maybe, but i dont know about that

Comment: So `S` is a set and it has 2019 elements, right?

Comment: Hint:  rewrite the requirement on the $A$s in terms of their complements.

Comment: This reminds me greatly of the lock puzzle but written from the other perspective, that you have a collection of keys you share among some bank officials such that two or fewer people could never have enough keys to open all the unique locks but three or more people always do.  I usually see it written in the form that you have a set number of people and you ask the fewest number of keys required.  I suspect that the solution will be similar and just needs to be rearranged.

Comment: Here is the related question I was referring to: [What is the minimum number of locks on the cabinet that would satisfy these conditions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581461/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-locks-on-the-cabinet-that-would-satisfy-these-cond)

Comment: I have attempted to write in a better way the text of your question. Do you agree ?

Comment: Indeed, one gets many hits with keywords "combinatorics safe multiple locks".

Comment: @peter.petrov I agree. However, the value $2019$ suggests the contest was held $\sim 3$ years ago. :)

Comment: @JeanMarie if you had done then it must be right(the editing)

Comment: Why say "$\{A_1,A_2, A_3,\cdots, A_n\}$ is a subset of the powerset of a set $S$", when you could say "$A_1,A_2, A_3,\cdots, A_n$ are subsets of a set $S$"? You are making us do unnecessary work!

Comment: @TonyK Sorry for the "supplementary work" ! My very heavy fault because it's the way I have undertaken to re-write the  initial text...

Comment: An interesting answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1047669)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let us consider an equivalent problem:

Let $A^c_1,\ldots, A^c_n$, for some integer $n$, each be subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, 2019\}$ so that:

A. The intersection of $A^c_i$ and $A^c_j$ is nonempty for any $i,j$.

B. For any $3$ distinct $i_1,i_2,i_3$,
the set $A^c_{i_1} \cap A^c_{i_2} \cap A^c_{i_3}$ is empty.

Then how large can $n$ be? Note that given $A^c_1,\ldots, A^c_n$, the sets $A_1,\ldots, A_n$, where each $A_i$ satisfies $$A_i = \{1,2,3,\ldots, 2019\} \setminus A^c_i,$$ satisfy the desired properties iff $A^c_1,\ldots, A^c_n$ satisfy A. and B. above.

Suppose we are given such an $A^c_1,\ldots, A^c_n$, for some $n$ that we do not know yet. Then from this we can construct a unique multigraph $G$ [perhaps more than one edge between a pair of vertices but each edge has $2$ endpoints] with $n$ vertices $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ and with a set $S$ of at most $2019$ edges; $S \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, 2019\}$, that satisfy the following:

1. For each $k \in S$ and each $i,j \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$: If $k$ is in $A^c_i \cap A^c_j$, then edge $k$ has endpoints $v_i$ and $v_j$.
2. Between $v_i$ and $v_j$ there is at least one edge. So $G$ is a multigraph with at most $2019$ edges and $G$ has a subgraph a *complete graph* on $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$.

Now, that this multigraph is well-defined i.e., every edge $k$ has at most $2$ endpoints follows from the fact that the $A^c_i$s satisfy B. above, or equivalently, there are *at most* $2$ integers $i$ such that $k$ is in $A^c_i$. [If $k$ is in only $1$ or $0$ of the $A^c_i$s then don't put $k$ into $S$.] Also, that there is at least one edge between $v_i$ and $v_j$ for each distinct $i,j$ follows from the fact that the $A^c_i$s satisfy A. above i.e., $A^c_i$ and $A^c_j$ intersect for each pair $i,j$.

Now, for $G$ to have at most $2019$ edges and have as a subgraph a complete graph on $n$ vertices [for some integer $n$] it follows that the following inequality holds:
$${n \choose 2} \le 2019,$$
or $n \le 64$.

We now construct $A^c_1, \ldots, A^c_{64}$. First, let $G'$ be the complete graph on $64$ vertices $\{v_1,\ldots, v_{64}\}$. So $G'$ has exactly ${{64} \choose 2}=$ $2016$ edges. Now add $3$ more edges between $v_1$ and $v_2$ and call the resulting graph $G$; this has exactly $2019$ edges. So now arbitrarily assign each edge in $G$ a unique number in $\{1,\ldots, 2019\}$. Then for each $i=1,\ldots, 64$, the integer $k \in \{1,2,\ldots, 2019\}$ is in $A^c_i$ iff there is an edge incident to $v_i$ assigned the number $k$. This gives the $A^c_1,\ldots, A^c_{64}$s. Check that the $A^c_i$s; $i=1,2,\ldots, 64$, indeed satisfy A. and B. above.

For each $i=1,2,\ldots, 64$, let $A_i=\{1,2,\ldots, 2019\} \setminus A^c_i$. Then that the $A^c_i$s; $i=1,2,\ldots, 64$, satisfy A. and B. above, imply that the $A_i$s; $i=1,2,\ldots, 64$, have the desired properties.

---

**ALTERNATIVE PROOF:** If you don't like graph theory, you can also look at it this way: For each $k \in \{1,2,\ldots, 2019\}$ such that $k$ is in at least $2$ of $A^c_1,\ldots, A^c_n$ [for some integer $n$] assign to $k$ a $2$-element subset $E_k=\{i,j\}$ of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, where $E_k=\{i,j\}$ satisfies both $k \in A^c_i$ and $A^c_j$.
That no $3$ of the $A^c_i$s intersect implies that for each such $k$ there are at most $2$ integers $i$, $j$ such that $k$ is in both $A^c_i$ and $A^c_j$. Thus, for each $k \in \{1,2,\ldots, 2019\}$, there is *at most* $1$ choice for $E_k$. That $A^c_i \cap A^c_j$ is nonempty for every $i,j \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ implies that for every one $E$ of the ${n \choose 2}$ $2$-element sets of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, there is a $k \in \{1,2,\ldots, 2019\}$ such that $E_k=E$.
So as there are ${n \choose 2}$ subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, this gives the inequality $${n \choose 2} \le 2019,$$
or as before, $n \le 64$.

Then to construct $A^c_1,\ldots, A^c_{64}$ that satisfy A. and B. as above, first assign for each $k \in \{1,2,\ldots, 2019\}$ a $2$-element subset $E_k$ of $\{1,2,\ldots, 64\}$, so that for every $2$-element subset $E$ of $\{1,2,\ldots, 64\}$, there is a $k$ such that $E=E_k$. As there are precisely $2016\le2019$ $2$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, 64\}$, this is possible. Then $k$ is in $A^c_i$ iff $i$ is in $E_k$.

Then for each $i=1,2,\ldots, 64$, set $$A_i=
\{1,2,\ldots, 2019\} \setminus A^c_i.$$